# Class StorageEngineUtil gone in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7

I am working on a code migration project from Liferay 6.2 to Liferay 7.1. In Liferay 6.2 there is a class

*com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.StorageEngineUtil*

from where the method **getFields(long classPK)** is used. However in Liferay 7.1 the method is gone and I cannot find a replacement for it.

Is anybody here familiar with my issue or Liferay in general and can provide me with some guidance?

Greetings, Michael

Comment: what about https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-1/breaking-changes, it says the package has been moved to com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.kernel

Comment: @André gave the correct link ([this](https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-1/breaking-changes#removed-operations-that-used-the-fields-class-from-the-storageadapter-inter) link leads directly to the relevant anchor). If you need additional help, it would be useful to know more about the context, e.g. the methods in which you use `StorageEngineUtil::getFields`.

Comment: @qutax thx for the answer. To give you a bit more context here, what was done in our Liferay 6.2 code is that we are at first getting an instance of the Fields class via StorageEngineUtil.getFields(classPK). And after that the Fields method .get(key) was used to get a field with a key.